# How to display left delete button UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, ios4

I have implemented the swipe to delete method and everything works perfectly. What do I need to do in order to have the row of delete buttons on the left side of the cell?

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `editing` property of the table view to YES.